# Move messages from file system to Outlook folder

Tags: vba, outlook

I can move emails to my file system. Is it possible to do the reverse? This is what I have tried:

```vb
Sub GetMSG()
Dim StrFolder As String
StrFolder = "G:\CP-Purchasing\Completed Projects"
ListFilesInFolder StrFolder, True 'True includes subfolders, false check only this folder
End Sub

Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolderName As String, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
Dim FileItem As Scripting.File
Dim strFile, strFileType
Dim MyMsg As MailItem
Dim FolderPick As Folder

Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)
Set FolderPick = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").PickFolder
For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
    strFile = FileItem.Name
    ' This code looks at the last 4 characters in a filename
    strFileType = LCase$(Right$(strFile, 4))
    If strFileType = ".msg" Then
        Debug.Print FileItem.Path
        Set MyMsg = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate(FileItem.Path)
        MyMsg.SaveAs (FolderPick)'This does not error, but also does not seem to work
        MyMsg.Move (FolderPick)'This errors
        Set objAttachments = Nothing
        Set MyMsg = Nothing
    End If
Next FileItem
If IncludeSubfolders Then
    For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
        ListFilesInFolder SubFolder.Path, True
    Next SubFolder
End If
Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

On `MyMsg.SaveAs (FolderPick)` I get no error message, but it also does not save the msg in the specified folder.

`MyMsg.Move (FolderPick)` errors with

> run-time error 424 "Object required".

Answer (score 1):

For further processing after the move, you need another object since the reference to myMsg is lost.

```vb
Set myCopiedMsg = myMsg.Move(folderPick)
Debug.Print myCopiedMsg.Parent.FolderPath
```

In your code for moving only:

```vb
' no brackets
myMsg.Move folderPick
```